# How do i change the color of a box if it was on a specific color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new into JavaScript and currently trying out some stuff. Anyways, I'm making a simple box that changes color `onclick` of a button. Answer so simple yet I just can't figure it out. Here's the HTML so far:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function changeColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function ifColor() {
  if (box.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeColor(); ifColor();">
    Change box color
</button>
```

When I press the button it only turns into blue and when I press it again nothing happens. if I remove the `ifColor` function, the button makes the box turn red only.

Comment: So you are executing the `changeColor()` method that sets it to red, and then executing the `ifColor()` method to check if it is red (which you just set it to), which changes it to blue.  Those two changes are going to happen so fast that the browser will only apply the blue color

Comment: if you're new to JS, please use a recent tutorial that teaches modern JS. Don't use `onclick` on the HTML side with direct JS calling, keep your HTML pure HTML, e.g. `<button id="btn">Change box color</button>` and then in your JS file _find that button_ using `const button = document.getElementById("btn")` (or any of the many other element-finding functions), and then use `button.addEventListener("click", evt => {...});` in order to handle clicks. Also, it's usually a bad idea to directly manipulate `style`; instead, you usually want to manipulate the `classList`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i was actually using addEventListener but posted it here as onclick just not to make the js code long :p

Comment: Please always post the code you're using. Reducing is fine, but rewriting to be something very different is a terrible idea =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one function that toggles the color.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function changeColor() {
  if (box.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeColor();">
    Change box color
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is functioning, just set a delay of certain seconds to view it change.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function changeColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function ifColor() {
setTimeout(()=>{
 if (box.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
},2000);
 
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeColor(); ifColor();">
    Change box color
</button>
```

Comment: i don't want the box to change color by itself or during an interval. If it is red, i press change color, it turns blue. However, if it's blue, i press the btn, it turns red... that's how i want it to work

Comment: @AhmadBenos, you can use an IIFE to make the background color default to blue or red, then use the function to toggle the color

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have it so, when you click the button, it changes colors between red and blue?

The way you have your code set up, it will always be blue because:

```
function changeColor() {
  box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function ifColor() {
  if (box.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

You first call changeColor(); which turns the button to red, then you run ifColor() which changes the button to blue. This happens pretty much instantaneously.

You just need to do this:

```
function changeColor() {
  if(box.style.backgroundColor === "red"){
      box.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } 
  else box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");

function changeColor() {
  if (box.classList.contains('red')) {
    box.classList.remove('red');
    box.classList.add('blue');
  } else {
    box.classList.remove('blue');
    box.classList.add('red');
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="red"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="changeColor();">
    Change box color
</button>
```